# I am trying to create package version for 2GP and am getting this error "No matching source was found within the package root directory"

Tags: managed-package, package, package-install

I am trying to create package version for 2GP using salesforce CLI as well as VSCode and I am getting this error "No matching source was found within the package root directory"

Following the steps mentioned in the below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_workflow.htm

Facing error at step 8

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your sfdx-project.json file and a list of your package directories that exist in your source tree (folders). Simply [edit] the question to add these details.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are repeating package creation steps, not something you should do when simply creating a new 2GP version. It would thus help if you explicitly listed the commands you are running too. Again, just [edit] to add.